# Determine if the sequence converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im trying to determine if the sequence converges or diverges:

${a_n} = \frac{(-1)^n\sqrt n}{n^2 + 1}$

And if it converges I need to find the limit.

What I tried was diving everything by $n^2$ to make it look a little easier but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: What does convergence mean to you? That is, what must a sequence satisfy to be classified as convergent? How can you test that?

Answer (score 3):

Take the limit and apply L'Hôpital's rule:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert a_n \rvert &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \, \frac{\sqrt n}{n^2 + 1} \\
&\underset{\text{L'H}}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/2 n^{-1/2}}{2n} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4n^{3/2}}\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Then, we know that $\lvert a_n \rvert~\text{converges} \implies a_n~\text{converges}$ (given that $\lvert a_n \rvert \to 0$, which it does), so we are done.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the correction! Perhaps I was thinking of series.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $n^2$ is a good idea:

$\displaystyle|a_n|=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+1}=\frac{\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\to\frac{0}{1+0}=0,\;\;$ so $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Divide denominator and numerator  by sqrt n. It will converge to zero (assuming, of course, n->infinity)

Comment: Yes that worked ok so I was just unsure if that was a good thing to do, so to the mathematician, would he accept me just randomly taking the limit as n approaches infinity, or should I state a theorem?

Comment: It will. I don't remember the name of the theorem, but having "bounded divided by infinity" will defininitely be zero to the satisfaction of any mathematician.